# How to localize a DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-5, winui-3

While developing my app in WPF i used that code for localizing:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.DwApplicationId}" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Now i try to upgrade the app to WinUI3, and there are no "x:Static" allowed. Also i have to use another way (Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader) to get the strings.

I googled for hours, but nothing found. Maybe anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Header` to a localized `TextBlock`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="DwApplicationId"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Or set the `Header` property programmatically:

```
col.Header = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("DwApplicationId");
```